# How to make a bi-way TCP relay in NodeMCU for the ESP8266

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm not sure NodeMCU can do this, I want to open a TCP port on two ESP8266 devices connected to the same network, data sent from either arrives on the other.
I've tried `net.createServer` and `net.createConnection`, neither of which seem to do the job, I assume `net.createServer` is browser only.

Example below of just using one device, and is just to test if I can send data from putty, but I get no output..

note: waiting for `wifi.sta.status() == 5` before launching the server makes no difference.

```
   wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
   wifi.sta.config(ssid,pwd)
   wifi.sta.connect()
   wifi.sta.setip({ip=ip,netmask="255.255.255.0",gateway=gateway})

   srv=net.createServer(net.TCP) 
   srv:listen(port,function(conn) 
     conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
      print(request) -- ! never happens  
     end)
   end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definitely works. We had something very similar just the other day at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36769999/131929.

**server.lua**

```
-- establish connection to AP
...

srv=net.createServer(net.TCP) 
srv:listen(5555, function(c) 
  c:on("receive", function(sck, data)
    print("received: " .. data)
    sck:send("echo: " .. data)
  end)
end)
```

**client.lua**

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("test", "password")
wifi.sta.setip({ip="192.168.0.199", netmask="255.255.255.0", gateway="192.168.0.1"})

srv = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
srv:on("receive", function(sck, data) print("received: " .. data) end)
srv:on("connection", function(sck)
  sck:send("foo")
end)
srv:connect(5555,"192.168.56")
```

**Testing**

I first started the server then sent TCP data from the command line

```
$ echo "foo" | nc -w1 192.168.0.56 5555
echo: foo
```

Ok, first test successful. Then I started the client on a second ESP8266 in the same subnet. Both were connected to their respective ESPlorer at the time. The server reported

> received: foo

while the client reported

> received: echo: foo

Be sure to also look up the functions used in this simple test in the API documentation at http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/net/.

Comment: Mate thankyou for clearing that up, I couldn't find a clearly explained  difference between those two functions, u nailed it.